# Use Typeahead template inside a twig

Tags: symfony, twig, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using symfony2 and want to use typeahead, I'm including configuration inside the twig and so I can't render the template because this syntax : `{{ var }}` is the same as Twig's. 
How can I work this out ?

This is the code for typeahead :

```
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  prefetch: '../data/repos.json',
  template: [
    '<p class="repo-language">{{language}}</p>',
    '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
    '<p class="repo-description">{{description}}</p>'
  ].join(''),
  engine: Hogan
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can use the [`{% verbatim %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) tag (as of 1.12) or [`{% raw %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/raw.html) tag (prior to 1.12) do temporary ignore Twig tokens:

```
{% verbatim %}
$('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'twitter-oss',
  prefetch: '../data/repos.json',
  template: [
    '<p class="repo-language">{{language}}</p>',
    '<p class="repo-name">{{name}}</p>',
    '<p class="repo-description">{{description}}</p>'
  ].join(''),
  engine: Hogan
});
{% endverbatim %}
```

> **original**
>   The only solution I know of is echoing those elements with Twig:
>
> ```
> $('.example-twitter-oss .typeahead').typeahead({
>   name: 'twitter-oss',
>   prefetch: '../data/repos.json',
>   template: [
>     '<p class="repo-language">{{ '{{language}}' }}</p>',
>     '<p class="repo-name">{{ '{{name}}' }}</p>',
>     '<p class="repo-description">{{ '{{description}}' }}</p>'
>   ].join(''),
>   engine: Hogan
> });
> ```

Comment: Can I use directly the Twig engine ?

Comment: Otherwise , your answer is correct dear sir, ut since symfony2 is using Twig for rendering HTML, I don't see any need for including an extra engine such as Hogan. 
If you could please say what you think, I'd be gratefull !

Comment: Thanks a lot! how about the Twig engine , can I use it instead of Hogan ?

Comment: @Sekai Hogan is a front-end templating engine, Twig a back-end. However, you may be able to replace Hogan with Twig.js